# Adding a counter in vb.net for an sql-query output

Tags: sql, vb.net, counter

Right now I'm working on a simple program in vb.net.
Choose 2 dates in the daytimepicker, press a button for an sql-query and save the result somewhere.
This works fine, but now I want to add an counter to the query.
One column just has the numbers 1,2,3 in it and I want to count each one.
Little example with an "output"
`

```
x x x 1 -> count 1
x x x 1 -> count 2
x x x 2 -> count 1
x x x 1 -> count 3
x x x 2 -> count 2
x x x 3 -> count 1
```

`
This counter then should be added to the datatable which is the result of the query, as a new column. Basicly an bill number.

I've tried to do this in  the read-function of the sql, but I'm just getting errors and I dont know why..still beta I guess.

```
    Do While myReader.Read()
        results = results & myReader.GetString("0") & ";" &
            myReader.GetString("1") & ";" &
            myReader.GetString("2") & ";" &
            myReader.GetDecimal("3") & ";" &
            myReader.GetInt32("4") & ";" &
            myReader.GetInt32("5") & ";" &
 ** thats basicly my reader, which puts an ; between everything because im saving it as .csv

        If myReader.GetInt32("5") = 1 Then
            nmb1 = nmb1 + 1
        **put nmb1 in the output"
        ElseIf myReader.GetInt32("5") = 2 Then
            nmb2 = nmb2 + 1
        **put nmb1 in the output"
        ElseIf myReader.GetInt32("5") = 3 Then
            nmb3 = nmb3 + 1
        **put nmb1 in the output"
        Else
            MsgBox("u failed")
        End If '& vbLf
    Loo
```

p

I'll hope you understand my question, because I'm kinda new to programming. If you need any further explonation, please ask.

Comment: you could do it with analytical function if your database support it.

Comment: can we see the query part of the code. how you retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

Turn on OptionStrict. It will help to avoid type mismatches and odd bugs.

```
Dim results String = ""
Dim nmb1 As Integer
Dim nmb2 As Integer
Dim nmb3 As Integer

Do While ...
...

        Select Case myreader.GetInt32("5")
            Case 1
                nmb1 += 1
                results &= $"; {nmb1}"
            Case 2
                nmb2 += 1
                results &= $"; {nmb2}"
            Case 3
                nmb3 += 1
                results &= $"; {nmb3}"
            Case Else
                MessageBox.Show("u failed")
        End Select
        'do you wand to put a hard return between records? 
        results &= vbCrLf
Loop
```

Comment: How do I add this to my existing myReader-function? The results I'm getting are kinda odd right now..
``

Comment: @AVK this would go in in place of your If...End If